# How to convert data from a custom format to CSV?

Tags: csv, etl

I have file that the content of file is as bellow, I have only output two records here but there is around 1000 record in single file:

```
           Record type : GR
            address : 62.5.196
             ID : 1926089329
     time : Sun Aug 10 09:53:47 2014
               Time zone : + 16200 seconds
         address [1] : 61.5.196
            PN ID : 412 1
          ---------- Container #1 (start) -------
          inID : 101
          ---------- Container #1 (end) -------
          timerecorded: Sun Aug 10 09:51:47 2014
          Uplink data volume : 502838
          Downlink data volume : 3133869
          Change condition : Record closed

--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Record type : GR
            address : 61.5.196
             ID : 1926089327
     time : Sun Aug 10 09:53:47 2014
               Time zone : + 16200 seconds
         address [1] : 61.5.196
            PN ID : 412 1
          ---------- Container #1 (start) -------
          intID : 100
          ---------- Container #1 (end) -------
          timerecorded: Sun Aug 10 09:55:47 2014
          Uplink data volume : 502838
          Downlink data volume : 3133869
          Change condition : Record closed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Record type : GR
            address : 63.5.196
             ID : 1926089328
     time : Sun Aug 10 09:53:47 2014
              Time zone : + 16200 seconds
         address [1] : 61.5.196
            PN ID : 412 1
          ---------- Container #1 (start) -------
          intID : 100
          ---------- Container #1 (end) -------
          timerecorded: Sun Aug 10 09:55:47 2014
          Uplink data volume : 502838
          Downlink data volume : 3133869
          Change condition : Record closed
```

my Goal is to convert this to CSV or txt file like bellow

```
Record type| address |ID | time | Time zone| address [1] | PN ID 
GR |61.5.196 |1926089329 |Sun Aug 10 09:53:47 2014 |+ 16200 seconds |61.5.196 |412 1
```

any guide would be great on how you think would be best way to start this, the sample that I provided I think will give the clear idea but in words I would want to read the header of each record once and put their data under the out put header.

thanks for your time and help or suggestion

Comment: Please avoid tagging with "every language that could be used". Only tag with the language that is actually used. Since no language is used, but rather this is a suggestion of an approach, it will likely be closed.

Comment: @user2864740 - I don't think that questions regarding algorithms are off topic, which is what this is; he's not asking for recommendations about which tool to use but rather *how to start*, which essentially means that he wants advice on the algorithm to use.

Comment: @syrion Then don't vote to close it. I find such questions generally Too Broad for this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a simple PHP script that will read a text file containing your data and write a csv file with the results. If you are on a system which has command line PHP installed, just save it to a file in some directory, copy your data file next to it renaming it to "your_data_file.txt" and call "php whatever_you_named_the_script.php" on the command line from that directory.

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("your_data_file.txt");

$matches;
preg_match_all("/Record type[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)address[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)ID[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)time[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)Time zone[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)address \[1\][\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)PN ID[\s\v]*:[\s\v]*(.+?)/su", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$csv_file = fopen("your_csv_file.csv", "w");
if($csv_file) {
    if(fputcsv($csv_file, array("Record type","address","ID","time","Time zone","address [1]","PN ID"), "|") === FALSE) {
        echo "could not write headers to csv file\n";
    }
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        $clean_values = array();
        for($i=1;$i<8;$i++) {
            $clean_values[] = trim($match[$i]);
        }
        if(fputcsv($csv_file, $clean_values, "|") === FALSE) {
            echo "could not write data to csv file\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($csv_file);
} else {
    die("could not open csv file\n");
}
```

This script assumes that your data records are always formatted similar to the examples you have posted and that all values are always present. If the data file may have exceptions to those rules, the script probably has to be adapted accordingly. But it should give you an idea of how this can be done.

**Update**

Adapted the script to deal with the full format provided in the updated question. The regular expression now matches single data lines (extracting their values) as well as the record separator made up of dashes. The loop has changed a bit and does now fill up a buffer array field by field until a record separator is encountered.

```
<?php

$text = file_get_contents("your_data_file.txt");

// this will match whole lines
// only if they either start with an alpha-num character
// or are completely made of dashes (record separator)
// it also extracts the values of data lines one by one
$regExp = '/(^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9][^:]*:(.*)$|^-+$)/m';

$matches;
preg_match_all($regExp, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$csv_file = fopen("your_csv_file.csv", "w");
if($csv_file) {

    // in case the number or order of fields changes, adapt this array as well
    $column_headers = array(
        "Record type",
        "address",
        "ID",
        "time",
        "Time zone",
        "address [1]",
        "PN ID",
        "inID",
        "timerecorded",
        "Uplink data volume",
        "Downlink data volume",
        "Change condition"
    );

    if(fputcsv($csv_file, $column_headers, "|") === FALSE) {
        echo "could not write headers to csv file\n";
    }

    $clean_values = array();
    foreach($matches as $match) {

        // first entry will contain the whole line
        // remove surrounding whitespace
        $whole_line = trim($match[0]);

        if(strpos($whole_line, '-') !== 0) {
            // this match starts with something else than -
            // so it must be a data field, store the extracted value
            $clean_values[] = trim($match[2]);
        } else {
            // this match is a record separator, write csv line and reset buffer
            if(fputcsv($csv_file, $clean_values, "|") === FALSE) {
                echo "could not write data to csv file\n";
            }
            $clean_values = array();
        }
    }
    if(!empty($clean_values)) {
        // there was no record separator at the end of the file
        // write the last entry that is still in the buffer
        if(fputcsv($csv_file, $clean_values, "|") === FALSE) {
            echo "could not write data to csv file\n";
        }
    }

    fclose($csv_file);

} else {
    die("could not open csv file\n");
}
```

Doing the data extraction using regular expressions is one possible method mostly useful for simple data formats with a clear structure and no surprises. As syrion pointed out in his answer, things can get much more complicated. In that case you might need to write a more sophisticated script than this one.

Comment: Thanks @janwschaefer I was looking for how to start this but you provided the solution, I appreciate your time and solution :D

Comment: sorry to bother you but it worked for sample file but when I did the changes and run for original file which have 33 fields it's not working it write the files with header but the content is not written, the only difference that the original file have is (a: it have 33 columns b: between these 33 field there is another line like this "---------- Container #1 (end) -------") what I did is changed for($i=1;$i<8 to for($i=1;$i<33 and also added fields in array and preg I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: The data is parsed from the data file using a regular expression (_preg_match_all(...)_). That expression is currently static, it assumes to encounter exactly the data format shown in your question. In order to make it deal with more fields, the regular expression has to be enhanced. That can be done the "stupid" way by just adding the missing fields. Or you could try to make it smarter so it can deal with any number of fields. Can you post a full example of your data fields (maybe three entries, with all separators and formatting)?

Comment: Thanks I have updated the question and added the fields as instructed... thanks for your time ... I could not added here as there is limitation in characters

Comment: Does the container #1 contain only one field intID for all entries in your file? In other words, is the number and order of fields always the same?

Comment: Yes, all fields name are the same it just repeat itself for each record the field name are static

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is creating an Extract/Transform script (the *ET* part of an *ETL*). I don't know which language you're intending to use, but essentially any language *can* be used. Personally, unless this is a massive file, I'd recommend Python as it's easy to grok and easy to write with the included [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

First, you need to understand the format thoroughly.

1. How are records separated?
2. How are fields separated?
3. Are there any fields that are optional?
4. If so, are the optional fields important, or do they need to be discarded?

Unfortunately, this is all headwork: there's no magical code solution to make this easier.  Then, once you have figured out the format, you'll want to start writing code.  This is essentially a series of data transformations:

1. Read the file.
2. Split it into records.
3. For each record, transform the fields into an appropriate data structure.
4. Serialize the data structure into the CSV.

If your file is larger than memory, this can become more complicated; instead of reading and then splitting, for example, you may want to read the file sequentially and create a Record object each time the record delimiter is detected. If your file is even *larger*, you might want to use a language with better multithreading capabilities to handle the transformation in parallel; but those are more advanced than it sounds like you need to go at the moment.